# Jupyter home page is blank with chrome browser

Tags: python, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook

I just download the newest anaconda, which includes the jupyter 1.0.0.
However, when I use 'jupyter notebook' in 'Anaconda Prompt' or cmd, it is shown that the jupyter lanched sucessfully, and the chrome browser opened automatically. 
However, the opened page titled 'Home', which is blank now. So I can not do anything with jupyter.

I have uninstall the jupyter and even uninstall anaconda many times, besides, the chrome is also updated to the newest version, but the problem is still existed.

Does anyone have some advice?

Comment: is there any errors on chrome console? You can check console via `Control+Shift+J` or `F12`

Comment: it said "Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8888/static/components/es6-promise/promise.min.js?v=f004a16cb856e0ff11781d01ec5ca8fe' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.", do you know what's the mean?

Comment: Check this issue: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4467
Maybe it will help

Comment: yeah I guess the link maria shared would help you

Comment: @sertsedat yes it is